# Equation $p\cdot q\cdot r=a^3-1+43\cdot (b^2-1)$

Tags: nt.number-theory

$p\cdot q\cdot r=a^3-1+43\cdot (b^2-1)$

p, q, r are primes.

a, b integers>0.

Is this equation a Mordell equation?
Has this equation infinitely many solutions?

Comment: Any motivation for this question? To a non-expert it looks completely arbitrary.

Comment: @abx I have not yet a particular motivation

Comment: No motivation?!

Comment: Is there any reason you picked 43?

Comment: Please don't ask random "unmotivated" questions. Note that this site was created for professional mathematicians and PhD students to help their research efforts. Of course anyone can ask and answer questions, but this is the level expected here.

Comment: @Robert, perhaps OP is in the $43$ cabal that has been asking questions involving $43$ here and on m.se for a while now. E.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3574600/is-a-number-congruent-to-344-pmod-559-always-congruent-to-10m-pmod-41 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3566264/3484-cdot-n-is-always-congruent-to-216-pmod-344 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564437/integers-of-the-form-215s129 and more.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't know about a cabal but from the quirks of idiom in certain recent questions, e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355415/has-this-diophantine-equation-infinitely-many-solutions-for-a-b-not-multiple , my guess is that a single user is creating unregistered accounts, using them to post these rather unmotivated questions, and then just creating new accounts the next time a question occurs to them

Answer (score 0):

Consider e.g. $b=1$ and $a = 2k+1$, so the equation becomes $pqr =2 k (4k^2 + 6k + 3)$.
The [generalized Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) implies there are infinitely many primes $k$ such that $4 k^2 +   6 k + 3$ is prime, so that we have a solution with $p=2, q=k, r=4k^2 + 6 k + 3, a=2k+1, b=1$. To date all nontrivial cases of that conjecture, including this one, remain open.